# How can I get Stripe Publishable and Secret keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stripe-payments

I have created a Stripe account. I don't have a company or something like that - just doing a web API for educational purposes.
How can I get Stripe Publishable and Secret keys? How can I use Stripe for educational purposes without using real information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the possibility to use test-keys. The publishable test key should look like this `pk_test_51xxxx...` and you can find it [here](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys). You can make sure you are in test_mode by checking the switch in the right top side (on PC, on mobile it might differ)

also you can take a look at this [Stripe test live modes](https://stripe.com/docs/keys#test-live-modes) it might help you.

Comment: as for you're question "how to use Stripe for educational purposes", just use it in test_mode, you can make good use of their "fake cards" to simulate payments, and also use their webhooks to listen for changes that Stripe encounters.